# Texture rebind on android cause potential memory leak?

Tags: opengl, java, android, opengl-es, memory

After context lost, I have to rebind all my textures. I want to it the *correct* way, so I check each handle for availability. It's done by calling `unloadFromVram()`, and then `loadToVram()`

first unload:

```
public final void unloadFromVram()
{
    GLContextState.forgetTexture(handle); // invalidate cache

    if (glIsTexture(handle)) // check whether handle is still a texture instance.
    {
        glDeleteTexture(handle); // delete handle if it is a texture instance.
        handle = GL_NONE;
    }
}
```

upload again:

```
public final void loadToVram()
{
    handle = glGenTexture();

    GLESContextState.activateTextureInSlot(0, handle); // GL.glActiveTexture(glSlot) and GL.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    if (owner.isCompressed())
    {
        glCompressedTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, textureData.getWidth(), textureData.getHeight(), 0, textureData.bytes);
    }
    else
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format,textureData.getWidth(), textureData.getHeight(), 0, format, type, textureData.bytes);
    }
}
```

What have I investigated:

1. After doing so, most of my textures appears black or have invalid content (perhaps from other textures, or content which was bound to this handle before *suspend*).
2. If `glIsTexture(handle)` fails, and the handle has not to be deleted - the texture behaves just fine.
3. If I comment the whole check and deletion in `unloadFromVram()` - **everything** works just fine.

I ***suppose***, if I won't delete bound handle - it will cause a memory leak, due to texture's data is still in memory, so I have to avoid it. What do I have to do with this?

Comment: glDeleteTexture is [not valid OpenGL ES](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteTextures.xml) which suggests that the code you've posted is not your actual code.  Can you please update this question with the code you're actually using.